# Populating fields of selected features in ArcPy

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-pro

I want to write a script (in ArcGIS Pro) that goes through the attribute tables of all of the **currently selected features**, looks for fields with specific names in those tables, and then populates all rows of that field with a specified value. Here is the “pseudocode” I’m brainstorming with:

```
## set variables
Work_Code = ‘321’
In_Build = ‘Yes’

## code
Apply all of the following only to currently selected features:
    If field WorkCode exists in attribute table;
        For value in WorkCode;
            Set WorkCode value = Work_Code
    If field InBuild exists in attribute table;
        For value in InBuild;
            Set InBuild value = In_Build
```

Does this logic work? Also, what type of ArcPy commands or functions are going to help me in my endeavor? (I've heard "UpdateCursor" is going to be important) Python n00b trying to get good here.

Comment: Start by breaking the steps down and figuring out how to do each one, then re-assemble them.  If you haven't already, definitely read [Guidelines for arcpy.mp - ArcGIS Pro | Documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/guidelines-for-arcpy-mapping.htm).  From there, you will have to identify the active map or the map with the selection you want to go through.  After the map, you will need to list layers and find any that have selections.  Then you get to the part of updating the data.

Comment: Use [ListFields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listfields.htm) and [da.UpdateCursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm)